# Spring Boot H2 db in Docker container

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, docker, h2

I have a basic Spring Boot app running in a container with an in memory H2 database.
I am able to run the container but seems that connection to the db fails.

```
2023-04-21T10:30:36.542599002Z org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure

SQL State  : 08S01
2023-04-21T09:51:54.117632638Z Error Code : 0
2023-04-21T09:51:54.117636830Z Message    : Communications link failure

2023-04-21T09:51:54.209294453Z Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  
app:

build:
  context: .

ports:
  - "8080:8080"

command: java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar /app.jar
```

properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

docker file:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: When you say "fails", what happens; can you [edit] the message to include your process's log messages?  Since H2 is an in-process in-memory database it shouldn't be any different running it in Docker or not.

Comment: You say you want to use H2, but the error indicates a MySQL connection string was used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies within your `spring.datasource.url` property. It should also contain the name of the database you want to connect to. For example: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb`.

Comment: If I run the app outside Docker works fine, so it is not that the reason I guess

Comment: Had you the chance to try it though? I'll be honest I only did a superficial research on the matter and as far as i can tell all examples i've found thus far all use a database name.

Comment: of course I tried

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

So you are allowing remote connections and you can access the h2 database in docker.